# Python How to keep tally of score

Tags: python

Trying to make a score based blackjack game. I have it running and everything is working except the score tally. It marks the point after the round but resets to 0 after. here is the section that is giving me issues

```
pScore = dScore = 0

def play()
    while len(deck) >= 4:

        deal(deck, phand, dhand)

        moves(deck, phand, dhand, player, dealer)

        win(player, dealer, dhand, phand, pScore, dScore)

def win(player, dealer, dhand, phand, pScore, dScore): 
    player = sum(phand)
    dealer = sum(dhand)

    if player == 21 and dealer != 21:
        pScore += 1
        print "Player wins!"
    elif player < 21 and player > dealer:
        pScore += 1
        print "Player wins!"
    elif player <= 21 and dealer > 21:
        pScore += 1
        print "Player wins!"
    elif dealer == 21 and player != 21:
        dScore += 1
        print "Dealer wins!"
    elif dealer < 21 and dealer > player:
        dScore += 1
        print "Dealer wins!"
    elif dealer <= 21 and player > 21:
        dScore += 1
        print "Dealer wins!"
    elif player == dealer:
        print "Push!"

    print "\nPlayer's Score= ", pScore, "\nDealer's Score= ", dScore, "\n"

    return (pScore, dScore)
```

Comment: This should probably be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. If you have a specific question about python, ask it here. Asking "why is my code not working" is not a suitable question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your variables to global:

```
def win(player, dealer, dhand, phand, pScore, dScore):
    global pScore = global dScore = 0
```